# Checking contract against contract type in Liquidity

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

With the example below, is it possible to get liquidity to check that the type of the contract `C` matches `C_intf`?

```
contract type C_intf = sig
  type storage
  val%entry check_balance : nat -> _
end

contract C = struct
  type storage = unit
  let%init storage = ()
  let%entry check_balance (bal : nat) storage =
    failwith "bouh"
end

type storage = address

let%entry main (some_c_contract : C_intf.instance) _ =
  failwith "hello"
```